# Etymology of the expression "to entertain an idea"

Tags: etymology, expressions, verbs

The expression ***[to entertain an idea/thought/etc.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/entertain-an-idea-hope-thought-etc)*** has perplexed me for a while now. Given the meaning of the verb *entertain*, I find it quite weird for it to be used in such a way. So, how did this come to be?

Comment: ..I don't think this is actually a "phrasal verb", more like a verb-noun collocation.

Comment: [Etymonline  has it the opposite](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=entertain) , that the meaning as "consider" was a little before the usage as "amuse".

Comment: It seems understandable in a metaphorical sense. You entertain a guest rather than slamming the door in their face. Here, the idea is the same as the guest. In other words, the idea is welcomed and paid attention to.

Comment: 'Entertain an idea' is certainly not a phrasal verb by any of the various definitions in use. It might qualify as an idiom now (a well-known usage, but involving a now unusual sense of a word). As @Cascabel says, it is a verbo-nominal idiom / fixed expression.  But Etymon answers the question of etymology.

Comment: user240918 Good – but the title needs correcting also.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Etymonline just sets a date of usage, but it doesn’t really explain how the sense come into usage.

Comment: The research should accompany the question (Etymon being a standard reference), and the question switched to 'How did the modern usage of 'entertain' arise?' (assuming Etymon doesn't answer this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In earlier senses, the word *entertain* can refer to supporting or maintaining something (Oxford English Dictionary, "entertain, v.," I), to holding things together (II), or to receiving or admitting something (III). Many kinds of things can be received or admitted: hosts entertain guests, for instance. Ideas and requests can also be entertained, as def. 9b (grouped under III) suggests:

> b. To give consideration to (an idea, request, etc.); to think about, contemplate.
>
> 1583   B. Melbancke Philotimus (new ed.) 201   I straightlie inhibit you for your better thriuing, neuer once **to enterteine one thoughte** of Aurelia.
>
> 1605   Bp. J. Hall Medit. & Vowes II. §53   But I will suspect a nouell **opinion** of vntrueth; and not **entertaine it**, vnlesse [etc.].
>
> 1665   R. Boyle Occas. Refl. ii. xi. sig. P7v   Who thinks it not time **to entertain thoughts** of Death.

Ideas, thoughts, and opinions could all be entertained, that is, considered or contemplated. For instance, in *[The Secretaries Studie](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A01403.0001.001?rgn=main;view=fulltext)* (Thomas Gainsford, 1616; link [to 1652 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=JHVCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22entertain%20a%20thought%20of%20alteration%22&source=bl&ots=osLNZYFgcb&sig=ACfU3U0JXQ_ukgAXXHnrq6wY8TCDzcg9cQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfuaiMyd_iAhVLZN8KHcQMBTwQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22entertain%20a%20thought%20of%20alteration%22&f=false)), where the speaker describes their own constancy against *entertaining a thought* of changing their mind:

> for why should you giue me any cause of suspition, when a warrant is sealed of our happinesse; or assume to your selfe a counterfeit libertie of trying my patience, when you know i will pul out mine owne heart, before it shall **entertain a thought** of alteration

The way we most often use **entertain** now, meaning to engage or amuse (IV), is related to these other three meanings, but they all emerge as distinct meanings fairly early (in the sixteenth century). Taking its literal Middle French meaning *entretenir* (*entre-* ~ among, *-tenir* ~ hold), each modern meaning is only a couple of steps away from holding something. So it's likely that III and IV distinguish themselves at this early moment in time by the kind of object they take; *entertaining* **someone** came to refer to holding them in a state of amusement or engagement. *Entertaining* **an abstraction** came to refer to holding it in one's thought.

Comment: Good answer. This is unrelated to the subject matter, but I am curious: Where did the last refrence come from? I found the last part of it very interesting; "when you know i [sic] will pul out mine owne heart, before it shall entertain a thought of alteration".

Comment: It came from *The Secretaries Studie*, which I linked to. The context is one lover chastising another for not addressing her with a lavish enough title. All of this is in a book that offers models for composing in various genres like amorous letters and thank you letters.

Comment: Of course, I had a brain malfunction I guess, and thought it was referring to the lines of text above it. I am sure to check it out.