# Is capitalization of the personal pronoun "I" a modern thing in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, capitalization, personal-pronouns, early-modern-english

In an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/501389/2923) to a question I asked, the user included an extract from a text seemingly written in older English. Not *Old English*, but definitely older English, made evident by the fact it spelled e.g. *own* and *owne*.

But another thing I noticed in it was that *I* was written without capitalization, as in *i*. I was wondering if this was a typo by the user, a typo by the original author of the writing, or if it was a feature of English at the time of writing.

Considering the user's answer was devoid of any other typos, and considering he probably *copypasted* the writing onto his post, I didn't believe he had made the potential mistake. If it was a mistake by the author, then, less likely, the user could have included a "[sic]" behind to signalize it was a fault of the original author and not him.

So, this is why I find it circumstantially likely that it was perhaps a feature of older English. Is this the case?

EDIT: I believe it is from early-modern-English. Not sure though, it is for the experts to say.

Comment: The accepted answer under that question will give you the origin of the capital ***I*** in English, along with much more information.

Comment: Considering that the source material of the extract where the lower-case "I" was in was written in either the sixteenth century of seventeenth century, I guess it was a typo of either the original author, the person putting his work on the internet, or the user who quoted it in his answer.